# Ho to route one subnet to another using firewalld CentOS 7

Tags: networking, vpn, centos, routing, firewalld

I have a CentOS 7 system, with a VPN host and one physical network interface.

I have my physical network interface assigned to `public` zone, while my VPN requests are going through `trusted`. Also, I have some servers, in docker containers routed to the latter zone.

I'd like, if my VPN and Docker containers to have internet connection, while retaining the subnet of `10.8.0.0/24` that I created on zone `trusted`.

The solution I'm thinking of involves forwarding request from `10.8.0.0/24` to out of the subnet to the physical interface, preferably with masquareding. If you have a better solution, I'm open to it.

So far, my `firewalld` config looks like this.

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp2s0
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 8080/tcp 23/tcp 1194/udp 80/tcp 443/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: docker0
  sources: 10.8.0.0/24 2001:0db8:ee00:abcd::/64
  services: openvpn
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused by the question, because I only have one NIC (physical one at least), which is connected to the internet, via a router. the IP is `192.168.0.241`. The VPN has a subnet of `10.8.0.0/24`, and the computer in question has the address of `10.8.0.1`. I was paying attention, not to have them overlap

Comment: Okay so try this..... `route add 10.8.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1` followed by `route add 10.8.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.241` but beforehand you might save the output of the `route print` somewhere to reference first. To delete those routes you can run `route delete 10.8.0.0` and `route delete 10.8.0.1`.... Think hard about this, have backup of your route table too and be sure you can revert it back out of have a backout method just in case.

Comment: If you add those two routes and there are problems, you can reboot too since they are not persistent so `route add 10.8.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1` first and then `route add 10.8.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.241` next. If there are issues, reboot and do not run the `route delete` commands. Still have the `route print` output of the IPv4 first though.

Comment: There has to be an IP on one subnet that can talk to an IP on another subnet that can then route via Layer 3 routing I think. I've configured static routes like that before on the client machines, and I've configured static routes in routers and firewalls too. There are other ways to do it with other protocols but for things like this, that's how I've handled some in the past. Maybe it will help or maybe not, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I don't think I have the `route` command. Is this a firewalld rich rule? or should I download a package? I'm sorry, I'm just getting into this stuff

Comment: I just get the how `Usage:...` text, makes me think the format is wrong somehow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88709/discussion-between-pimp-juice-it-and-laszlo-stahorszki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my absence, I had other things to do in the meantime, but I did manage to solve the problem.

However, the solution is kind of disappointing. The only thing I needed to do was to enable masquerading on the public zone